# google pageinsights algorithm giving inconsistent results

Tags: google-chrome, google-pagespeed, google-developer-tools

After google page view algorithm changed, the pageinsights score is giving inconsistent results for webpage. sometimes it shows greater than 90 and sometimes shows in between 60 to 75.

suggestions provided by google pageinsights to improve performance is also inconsistent.

Lighthouse(i.e audit) in chrome giving consistent results : 80 score.

will googlepageinsights consider Google DFP Banner in First Paint ?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That tool is not consistent.  However working with the tool for a while I realized that the tool is  accurate.  There will be few variations, since it calculated some weightage against field data of last 28 days.

On the page insight tool click on "See calculator" which provides you with the calculated value. From my experience, after 28 days if there is no change in your site the value will match.